# What is the type of this encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am taking interest in various encryption methods and I was wondering if there is a way of determining the type of encryption being used in these strings:

S75010_570 encrypts to 3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e

ee892dafe641fdda991703e846

Is it not Hexidecimal keys?

Thank you!

Comment: ​​​​​No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​, there is not - this type of question has been asked a few times before ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847245/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-string-with-unknown-decryption), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980720/most-effective-way-to-decrypt-data-when-encryption-method-is-unknown))

Comment: Thanks, I will have a read.

Comment: Think about it like this: how do you know the string is encrypted? What if the encryption algorithm is just "add a random character to the beginning of the string" (and decrypting it is just removing that character)? There are infinite possibilities of how it could have been encrypted (some more likely than others, but still infinite). With only the encrypted string, it's simply not possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Comment: I have the decrypted strings. However it seems like it isn't possible to figure out the approach. Thanks for the explanations

Comment: @hello See my comments to ray's answer. I think you may be jumping to the incorrect conclusion that 3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e decrypts to S75010_570.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a way to figure that out like that.

Comment: I have added another one. Will this help ?

Comment: @hello: No it does not. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the problem that cannot be addressed in the limited SO space.

Comment: @hello No. Consider: "I have some encrypted messages, they are 'no', 'yes', and 'maybe'. Can you figure out what kind of encryption is being used?" Umm, no, we can't. "No" could mean "no", "yes", zero, "don't go to Atlanta" or anything else. We'd need to know something about the scheme or something about what at least one of them decrypt to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one of the decrypted strings which I have updated in the post. However it does seem impossible to find out. Thanks again!

Comment: @hello So can you 100% confirm that you have some way to turn "3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e" into "S75010_570"? (Saying that you can go the other way is *not* the same thing!)

Comment: @hello For example, consider a program that sums the digits of its inputs to produce the output. It can turn "10329" into "16". But that doesn't mean that "16" decrypts to "10329"! You'd need a way to turn "16" into "10329" to say that, which clearly is not possible.

Comment: I can confirm that the string "S75010_570" encrypts into "3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e". However it does makes sense that particular set of characters in the encrypted string will not equate to a single character in the original string. Thank you for your detailed input @davidschwartz

Comment: Right, but did you confirm that "3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e" decrypts to "S75010_570"? Do you understand my explanation why these are different things? By summing digits, "1034" encrypts to "8", but "8" does not decrypt to "1034". -- Or to put it more specifically, what makes you think the algorithm is an encryption algorithm?

Comment: I understand the explanation. I have a site that translates the string "S75010_570" into "3177a84a758405e4c00f960b1e" and this does not change. I.e the same output string for the particular input string. I am trying to determine the approach that could have been taken and assumed it is encryption but it clearly seems impossible.

Comment: @hello Why do you think that's encryption? I can make a site that sums the digits of a number. Every time you enter "1034", it will output "8". But that's *not* encryption, and decryption is not possible. Do you have any evidence that it is encryption? It seems that you have jumped to a (likely false) conclusion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I bet my bottom dollar it's a hashing algorithm.

Comment: The value `S75010_570` hashes to `a9ad0f6cbf0e0a0b4ffd163a5900d5bf` if the MD5 algorithm is used. I'm wondering if the site is simply changing the base *encoding*. Will look a bit into it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Checked if it was simply changing the base *encoding*, but the output doesn't match any of the following bases: 16, 32, or 64. Therefore, it does not appear to be a base encoding change.

Comment: UPDATE: I found out its UUID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score -1):

It's like a MD5, but I cannot be sure about this. It can be only a char equivalent substation... There are some sites to decrypt MD5. You can try some of these site to test if it's a MD5. Just search for MD5 decrypt

Comment: I have checked to no avail. I have updated the post with the decrypted string.

Comment: You don't "encrypt" and "decrypt" with MD5.  MD5 is a hashing algorithm.  You "hash" and thats it.

Comment: @LukePark: You're correct. It seems Pablo here is confusing *decryption* with *cracking* based on pre-generated rainbow tables.

Comment: Also, see my comment on MD5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365874/what-is-the-type-of-this-encryption/36366053#comment60353821_36365914)